# Restart apache on Docker

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, htaccess

I am trying to update my `.htaccess` file on a Docker container. After updating the file, I need to restart Apache. Whenever I try to restart Apache using the command `service apache2 restart`, I get the following error:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. The Apache error log may have more information. ...fail!
```

When I got to the error log, there are no new errors. This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-curl vim

# Install app
RUN rm -rf /var/www/*
ADD src /var/www

# Configure apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; command to restart apache in your case is `kill -USR1 1`

Few things needs to be cleared here:

1. Your docker image is running apache directly using CMD.
2. this means apache main process will always have PID=1, and you are not using init system.
3. You are trying to restart apache by using `service` command which relies on init system. Doh
4. Alternative way of gracefully restarting apache is to send signal to main process. Read more here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/stopping.html

Answer (score 0):

According to your Dockerfile you include your HTML files when when creating your docker image:

```
ADD src /var/www
```

So could you explain why you need to edit an .htaccess file after running your image? If you need a different .htaccess file on different hosts, the "docker" way would be to use a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume) when running your container:

```
docker run -v /path/to/host.htaccess:/var/www/.htaccess user/image
```